# Java Regex: How detect a URL with file extension

Tags: java, regex, string, url

How create a **REGEX** to detect if a "String url" contains a file extension (*.pdf,.jpeg,.asp,.cfm...*) ?

Valids (without extensions):

- http://www.yahoo.com
- http://dbpedia.org/ontology/
- http://www.rdf.com.br

Invalids (with extensions):

- http://www.thesis.com/paper.pdf
- http://pics.co.uk/mypic.png
- http://jpeg.com/images/cool/the_image.JPEG

Thanks,
Celso

Comment: What do you mean by *contains a file extension*? Do you mean *ends with one of these strings*? Can you give a few examples of what you don't want to match?

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you are better off using [String.endsWith()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) This is faster and easier to read. 
Example:

```
"file.jpg".endsWith(".jpg") == true
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
// assuming the file extension is either 3 or 4 characters long
public boolean hasFileExtension(String s) {
    return s.matches("^[\\w\\d\\:\\/\\.]+\\.\\w{3,4}(\\?[\\w\\W]*)?$");
}

@Test
public void testHasFileExtension() {
    assertTrue("3-character extension", hasFileExtension("http://www.yahoo.com/a.pdf"));
    assertTrue("3-character extension", hasFileExtension("http://www.yahoo.com/a.htm"));
    assertTrue("4-character extension", hasFileExtension("http://www.yahoo.com/a.html"));
    assertTrue("3-character extension with param", hasFileExtension("http://www.yahoo.com/a.pdf?p=1"));
    assertTrue("4-character extension with param", hasFileExtension("http://www.yahoo.com/a.html?p=1&p=2"));

    assertFalse("2-character extension", hasFileExtension("http://www.yahoo.com/a.co"));
    assertFalse("2-character extension with param", hasFileExtension("http://www.yahoo.com/a.co?p=1&p=2"));
    assertFalse("no extension", hasFileExtension("http://www.yahoo.com/hello"));
    assertFalse("no extension with param", hasFileExtension("http://www.yahoo.com/hello?p=1&p=2"));
    assertFalse("no extension with param ends with .htm", hasFileExtension("http://www.yahoo.com/hello?p=1&p=a.htm"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative version without regexp but using, the URI class:

```
import java.net.*;

class IsFile { 
  public static void main( String ... args ) throws Exception { 
    URI u = new URI( args[0] );
    for( String ext : new String[] {".png", ".pdf", ".jpg", ".html"  } ) { 
      if( u.getPath().endsWith( ext ) ) { 
        System.out.println("Yeap");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Works with:

```
java IsFile "http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getPath()"
```

Comment: This is a much better approach particularly in a filter where you already have a requestURI.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Java developer anymore, but you could define what you're looking for with the following regex

```
"/\.(pdf|jpe{0,1}g|asp|docx{0,1}|xlsx{0,1}|cfm)$/i"
```

Not certain what the function would look like.

Comment: You probably want ? rather than {0,1} for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

If the following code returns true, then contains a file extension in the end:

```
urlString.matches("\\p{Graph}+\\.\\p{Alpha}{2,4}$");
```

Assuming that a file extension is a dot followed by 2, 3 or 4 alphabetic chars.